# Change TFT to Retina in iphone

Tags: iphone

There are people who insist that for changing design from TFT to Retina we should redesign all app.
But I have read that we can change only app's images ,and it's enough. 
I want to know which is the best practice for it and which solution is acceptable??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Retina Display](http://www.apple.com/ipodtouch/features/retina-display.html) is just Apple's name for the high resolution display on some of its devices -- it's still a TFT (thin film transistor) LCD display, though.

The Retina Display has twice as many pixels in each direction as the non-Retina version. iOS features a mechanism for providing both high resolution and standard resolution images, so that the high-res versions will be used if needed. All you need to do is include high-res versions of your images with the same names and their standard-res counterparts and the "@2x" suffix. Of course, having that higher resolution available means that you might want to [add detail to your images](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) or otherwise redesign your app to take full advantage of the screen's capabilities, but it's not a requirement. In fact, you don't *need* to do anything at all -- your existing app will work just fine without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your app.

In many cases simply including the hi-res versions of your images will be all that you need to do.

However, if you have any custom drawing that could benefit from the extra resolution, then you'll need to considered updating that code too.